# I have a huge problem with the form

Tags: 7, forms, log-messages

I want a form with checkboxes that will have all the severity levels and when the user (e.g selects only the error i want to select only the errors from watchdog. My problem now is that in watchdog the severities are with numbers :/ :/ :/.....here is my form:

```
/**
 * Settings form for the user.
 */
function kkkk_admin_settings() {

    // Form for the severity checkboxes.
    $kkkk_severity_levels = variable_get('kkkk_severity_levels', array());

    // Declare empty options array.
    $kkkk_severity_options = array();

    // Loop through each severity level and push to options array for form.
    foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $number_select => $severity) {
      $kkkk_severity_options[$severity] = drupal_ucfirst(
        $severity);
    }
    $kkkk_form['kkkk_severity_levels'] = array(
      '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
      '#title'         => t('Type of log messages'),
      '#options'       => $kkkk_severity_options,
      '#default_value' => array_values($kkkk_severity_levels),
      '#required'      => TRUE,
    );
    dsm($kkkk_severity_levels);
    return system_settings_form($kkkk_form);
  }
}
```

this `dsm($kkkk_severity_levels);`if i have selected error gets me out:

```
error (String, 4 characters ) error
emergency (Integer) 0
alert (Integer) 0
critical (Integer) 0
warning (Integer) 0
notice (Integer) 0
info (Integer) 0
debug (Integer) 0
```

I need to take out :

```
    error (String, 4 characters ) 3
    emergency (Integer) 0
    alert (Integer) 0
    critical (Integer) 0
    warning (Integer) 0
    notice (Integer) 0
    info (Integer) 0
    debug (Integer) 0
```

where 3 is the number of the error severity. I need to take this number in order in my function to select only the error messages from watchdog.... Could someone help?? If I need a new form could you help with that form plz ?? I am new in coding.. :/ :/ :/

Comment: That '#default_value' looks wrong to me. You're assigning an array to it. Perhaps you want to set that statically, or do a string match in your options loop to assign the value for the default you want. Sorry, I see it's checkboxes, I thought it was a select. What do you get if you `dsm($kkkk_severity_options)`?

Comment: For future questions, I suggest making the title more descriptive - the current title gives little meaningful information to readers.

Comment: dsm($kkkk_severity_options) gets me out:emergency (String, 9 characters ) Emergency,
alert (String, 5 characters ) Alert,
critical (String, 8 characters ) Critical,
error (String, 5 characters ) Error,
warning (String, 7 characters ) Warning,
notice (String, 6 characters ) Notice,
info (String, 4 characters ) Info,
debug (String, 5 characters ) Debug ,

Comment: and if i change the line with $kkkk_severity_options[$severity]=drupal_ucfirst($severity) and put $kkkk_severity_options[$number_select] = drupal_ucfirst($severity);

Comment: dsm(kkk_severity-options) gets me out 0 (String, 9 characters ) Emergency,
1 (String, 5 characters ) Alert
2 (String, 8 characters ) Critical
3 (String, 5 characters ) Error,
4 (String, 7 characters ) Warning,
5 (String, 6 characters ) Notice,
6 (String, 4 characters ) Info,
7 (String, 5 characters ) Debug,

Comment: but  dsm($kkkk_severity_levels); gets me out 3 (String, 4 characters ) 3,
0 (Integer) 0,
1 (Integer) 0,
2 (Integer) 0,
4 (Integer) 0,
5 (Integer) 0,
6 (Integer) 0,
7 (Integer) 0, and it is not what i am really looking for!!because it ticks me also the 0-0

Comment: look if i have the code as in example and i have these values error (String, 4 characters ) error,
emergency (Integer) 0,
alert (Integer) 0,
critical (Integer) 0,
warning (Integer) 0,
notice (Integer) 0,
info (Integer) 0,
debug (Integer) 0,
how i can change the keys(emergency, error, warning, alert, e.t.c) and put as keys the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7??? it also solves my problem

Comment: If you're wanting assign an index value to each option, you can add that when constructing your options array. Try this:

`foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $index => $label) {
  $kkkk_severity_options[$index] = ucfirst($label);
}`

Comment: that is what i tell you in the comments..look the first comment under yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23691/discussion-between-murraybiscuit-and-karmen).